# How to get the "name" of the key combination (keybind key) for the Openbox config file

Tags: lubuntu, openbox

It is one more attempt to get `Fn` keys to volume up/down, brightness, etc. working. Those controls are simply not working in my non-branded ultrabook.

In the configuration file:

> /home/yourname/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml

We can find the following code:

```
<!-- Keybinding for Volume management -->
<keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
    <action name="Execute">
        <command>amixer -q sset Master 3%+ unmute</command>
    </action>
</keybind>
```

So I guess if we find the correct keybind key, it will work. Am I right? If so, how?

Note: I'm using the default keyboard, pc105

Note 2: [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370304/xf86-keybinds-in-openbox), for the [XF86 keyboard](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/x11proto/tree/XF86keysym.h), the format of the keys seems something like 0x1008FF12 (code for mute in that keyboard). According with that answer, the keybind key is a shortcut to a file where that code is.

Note 3: [in this forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187155), there is an attempt to do it with xbindkeys. Unfortunately, xbindkeys doesn't seem to capture the `Fn` key for me.

Note 4: after modifing the configuration file, we have to run `openbox --reconfigure`

Comment: Not the Fn key, you need to press Fn _with_ something.

Comment: @terdon, if I push Fn+something, xbindkeys keep waiting to receive a key combination = xbindkeys doesn't semm to capture the Fn key

Comment: ah, sorry, I'd understood that you were hitting Fn alone. You _are_ using `xbindkeys -k` right? Try `xev` as suggested below too. Note that each movement of the mouse is reported as an event by `xev` so it can be a pain to find the key you want in its output.

Comment: @terdon, I realized that it depends on the key pressed. Fn+F4 is not detected (painted as volume up in my keyboard), but Fn+u is working (painted as the number 4 in my keyboard).

Comment: @terdon, I'm using the GUI (`xbindkeys-config`). Anyway, I just tried `xbindkeys -k` with the same result: Fn+F4 is not detected either

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not on a notebook right now and can't test if this works for <kbd>Fn</kbd>-combinations but I generally use `xev` for getting the appropriate keycodes:

```
xev | sed -ne '/^KeyPress/,/^$/p'
```

This should launch a window:

[image]

Keys pressed while the window is in focus will be printed to the command output. E.g. for left <kbd>Win</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x2d1, subw 0x0, time 42368858, (158,73), root:(934,383),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

If you wanted to assign this key to an openbox shortcut you would use `Super_L` (third line, second item in brackets).

`xev` is part of the `x11-utils` package and should be preinstalled on Ubuntu.

Comment: Very nice answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't detect all the combinations of my keyboard. For example, Fn+F4 is not detected (painted as volume up in my keyboard), but Fn+u is detected (painted as the number 4 in my keyboard).

Comment: I think this question is already solved. I have continued looking for a solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/468326/some-keys-are-not-detected-in-my-keyboard-multimedia-keys-by-either-xev-or-xb