# keybind to toggle touchpad in lubuntu (openbox)

Tags: scripts, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, touchpad, regex

I'm using lubuntu.
I want to add a shortcut to toggle (turn on and off) my touchpad.

I know I need to edit the xml file in ~/.config/openbox (in my case it's lubuntu-rc.xml) [as described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370304/xf86-keybinds-in-openbox) and [here](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Openbox:_Control_Screen_Brightness_Using_the_Keyboard)

I want it to trigger it when Fn and F5 are pressed (on my dell there is a touchpad icon on it, so I assume it triggers also a x86 keybind, dunno if that matters)

on my machine

```
 synclient TouchPadOff=1
```

turns off the touchpad, and

```
  synclient TouchPadOff=0
```

turns it on again.

The command

```
synclient
```

without any options, returns this list

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge = 300
    RightEdge = 1700
    TopEdge = 210
    BottomEdge = 1190
    FingerLow = 12
    FingerHigh = 15
    MaxTapTime = 180
    MaxTapMove = 107
    MaxDoubleTapTime = 180
    SingleTapTimeout = 180
    ClickTime = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ = 141
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW = 7
    VertScrollDelta = 48
    HorizScrollDelta = 48
    VertEdgeScroll = 1
    HorizEdgeScroll = 0
    CornerCoasting = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll = 0
    MinSpeed = 1
    MaxSpeed = 1.75
    AccelFactor = 0.0819336
    TouchpadOff = 0
    LockedDrags = 0
    LockedDragTimeout = 5000
    RTCornerButton = 2
    RBCornerButton = 3
    LTCornerButton = 0
    LBCornerButton = 0
    TapButton1 = 1
    TapButton2 = 3
    TapButton3 = 0
    ClickFinger1 = 1
    ClickFinger2 = 1
    ClickFinger3 = 0
    CircularScrolling = 0
    CircScrollDelta = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger = 0
    CircularPad = 0
    PalmDetect = 0
    PalmMinWidth = 10
    PalmMinZ = 100
    CoastingSpeed = 20
    CoastingFriction = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ = 15
    PressureMotionMaxZ = 80
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect = 1
    GrabEventDevice = 1
    TapAndDragGesture = 1
    AreaLeftEdge = 0
    AreaRightEdge = 0
    AreaTopEdge = 0
    AreaBottomEdge = 0
    HorizHysteresis = 12
    VertHysteresis = 12
    ClickPad = 0
```

as you can see, there is the line "TouchpadOff = 0".

So what I'm basically asking for is someone who knows how to work grep and regular expressions to tell me how to write a shell script that reads the output of snyclient and  executes "synclient TochPadOff=0" or "synclient TochPadOff=1" accordingly.

If found this [script that does something very similar](https://gist.github.com/egroeper/3f1212275689fec48e8e) , but I'm struggeling on the grep part.

If found a [generic toggle script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147080/shell-script-to-toggle-between-two-commands) , but I think grepping the info is cleaner.

I also already know [how to bind a shellscript to a keyboardshortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648922/lubuntu-hotkey-to-toggle-displays) from that example.

help greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  TOGGLE=$HOME/.toggle

  if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
    touch $TOGGLE
    synclient TouchPadOff=1 &
  else
    rm $TOGGLE
    synclient TouchPadOff=0 &
  fi

exit 0
```

There doesn't seem to be need for `grep`. Also, I'm not too sure that Openbox likes <kbd>Fn</kbd> in  any rc.xml but see [Nivatius' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/725366/248158) for how to use keypresses involving <kbd>Fn</kbd>. I've only ever used <kbd>Super</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>. I can bind that script to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, for example.

```
<keybind key="C-S-F5">        # Toggle touchpad
  <action name="Execute"><command>/home/dkb/bin/toggle-touchpad</command></action>
</keybind>
```

Comment: thanks. with xev I found the keycode for the Fn+F5 combo

Answer (score 1):

I settled for this solution:

script

```sh
# This shell script is PUBLIC DOMAIN. You may do whatever you want with it.

TOGGLE=$HOME/.touchpadtoggle

if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
    touch $TOGGLE
    synclient TouchpadOff=1
else
    rm $TOGGLE
    synclient TouchpadOff=0
fi
```

config file

```xml
<!-- toggle touchpad with fn key fn+F5 -->
    <keybind key="XF86TouchpadToggle">
     <action name="Execute">
          <command>~/scripts/touchpadtoggle.sh</command>
         </action>
    </keybind>
```

The path in command of course, needs to point to your script

I used xev to find out the XF code of fn+F5:

run xev, press Fn key and F5 then close the popup,
scroll up in the long output and look out for the keycode.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to dig out the `Fn+F5` code. BTW, this code cleans up the `xev` output: `xev | awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }'`. I found it here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_keyboard_keys#In_Xorg

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I placed in my ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml

```xml
<keybind key='XF86TouchpadToggle'>
    <action name='Execute'>
        <command>bash -c "synclient TouchpadOff=$(expr \( $(synclient | grep TouchpadOff | cut -d = -f 2) + 1 \) % 2)"</command>
    </action>
</keybind>
```

COMMENT
`synclient` (second one): lists actual parameters
`grep` : select the line referring to Touchpad
`cut -d = -f 2` : get only the part after "="
`expr \( ... + 1 \) %2` : increment by 1 and get the reminder of division by 2 (ie toggle 0/1)
`synclient TouchpadOff=` : set TouchpadOff to the result of above
`bash -c "..."` : make sure all the above is run in a bash shell.

This way I don't need a separate shell script. But you can easily put everything into a script if you prefer.